# Absolute value function in squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

If you have something like $\lim_{x\to 0} |x| \sin(\cdot)$ and are using the squeeze theorem, would you do something like $-|x| \leq \sin(\cdot) < |x|$? $|-x|$? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. $$-1 \leq \sin(\cdot) \leq 1 \implies -|x| \leq |x| \sin(\cdot) \leq |x|,$$and now apply $\lim_{x \to 0}$ to get: $$ 0 = \lim_{x \to 0}-|x| \leq \lim_{x \to 0}|x| \sin(\cdot) \leq \lim_{x \to 0}|x| = 0 \implies \lim_{x \to 0}|x|\sin(\cdot) = 0.$$